# Without copying, how do I print part of a std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20

Assume that I want to print the first word. The most obvious way would be like this:

```
string line = "Hello Hello";
const auto space_iter = find(line.cbegin(), line.cend(), ' ');
cout<<string(line.cbegin(), space_iter)<<endl;
```

But I'm printing profiling logs for my game at over 60fps, so such memory allocation and copying matters.

I also tried `std::span`:

```
string line = "Hello Hello";
const auto space_iter = find(line.cbegin(), line.cend(), ' ');
cout<<span(line.cbegin(), space_iter)<<endl;
```

But it seems that `std::cout` can't print a `std::span`, and gcc gives me 500+ lines of errors.

Comment: Have you heard of [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)? It's basically `std::span` for strings

Comment: @alter_igel Thanks, by simply replacing spac with std::string_view it now works. Though somehow clangd doesn't recognize it despite clang does.

Comment: *"The most obvious way would be like this:"* -- maybe most obvious to you, but not to me... People throw around the word "obvious" far more often than is warranted.

Comment: @JaMiT   Obviously!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++20 [gives `std::string_view` a convenient constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) that takes contiguous iterators. Like those of `std::string`. Pre-C++20, getting a substring as a `string_view` was a bit more complex, but now it's pretty trivial:

```
cout << std::string_view(line.cbegin(), space_iter) << endl;
```